# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running cross validation on dataset and getting

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

error at the beginning of second iteration of for loop of kFCVEvaluate. What am I doing wrong?

I looked at other posts about this error, they are about using and/or operators but I don't use any logical operators.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
model = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 42, max_depth=5)

def split_dataset(dataset): 
        numFolds=10 
        dataSplit = list()
        dataCopy = list(dataset)
        foldSize = int(len(dataset) / numFolds)
        for _ in range(numFolds):
            fold = list()
            while len(fold) < foldSize:
                index = randrange(len(dataCopy))
                fold.append(dataCopy.pop(index))
            dataSplit.append(fold)
        return dataSplit
    
def kFCVEvaluate(dataset):

    folds = split_dataset(data)
    scores = list()
    for fold in folds:
        trainSet = list(folds)
        trainSet.remove(fold)
        trainSet = sum(trainSet, [])
        testSet = list()
        for row in fold:
            rowCopy = list(row)
            testSet.append(rowCopy)
            
        trainLabels = [row[-1] for row in trainSet]
        trainSet = [train[:-1] for train in trainSet]
        model.fit(trainSet,trainLabels)
        
        actual = [row[-1] for row in testSet]
        testSet = [test[:-1] for test in testSet]
        
        predicted = model.predict(testSet)
        
        accuracy = actual-predicted
        scores.append(accuracy)
        print(scores)
kFCVEvaluate(data)
```

Comment: I looked at other posts about this error, they are about using and/or operators but I don't use any logical operators.

Comment: where's the traceback?

Comment: Having already asked for traceback, I probably shouldn't be doing this.  But if I had to guess, `trainSet.remove(fold)` is the problem line.  List `remove` selects the item to remove by value (actually `id` first).  So it iterates through the list until it finds an item that `==` the test case.  But if the list contains arrays, you'll the `arr1==arr2` test, which will return a bolean array.  But the `remove` can only accept a simple True/False.

Comment: The duplicate talks about pandas Series, while your error is for an array.  In any case the issue using a multielement boolean in a python context that expects a scalar boolean.  `if`, `and`, `or` are common contexts.  I don't see any of those here (except the while).  The `any/all` fix only applies to a subset of the cases.  But the first task is to identify which operation has the error.  The actual fix will vary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing my `remove` hypothesis

```
In [214]: alist = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.ones(3), np.array([4,5])]
In [215]: alist.remove(np.array([1,2,3]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-215-0b2a68765241>", line 1, in <module>
    alist.remove(np.array([1,2,3]))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`remove` does work if the list contains lists or tuples

```
In [216]: alist = [[1,2,3], [1,1,1], [4,5]]
In [217]: alist.remove([1,1,1])
In [218]: alist
Out[218]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```